# visualizar y crear eventos en google calendar con php y html

Tags: php, html, google-api, google-calendar

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para agendar incidencias a técnicos y se ha pensado usar la API de google Calendar, pero me encuentro atascado para crear todo el proceso. He realizado el ejemplo del quickstart que hay en google, ejecuto el comando en la terminal, copio el enlace, me redirige a elegir la cuenta de google, pero cuando le doy a permitir ver eventos y demás... Me redirige a la aplicación, que hay que ejecutarla desde consola... También he tenido que añadir esta línea

```
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/calendario/salida.php');
```

Porque si no, me da un error 404. Adjunto todo el código y agradezco si alguien me puede explicar el proceso para poder crear eventos y poder visualizarlos, ya que no encuentro nada de verdad claro y con fundamento.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/calendario/salida.php');
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ .'/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido llegar con este código que voy a colocar posteriormente al último paso de validación. Pero no se a donde tendría que redirigir al usuario después de que iniciara sesión. Agradezco toda ayuda, por favor.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    // print_r($_SESSION);
     if(isset($_GET["logout"])){
      session_destroy();
     }
    $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/logueado.html';
    require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();

    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('143244856172-dfr1qom3ea7dt4an1ue25c33da6on0jj.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('nNHq7DcLHqAnEa4jsDfIMQg_');
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->addScope('profile');

    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);


    print_r($client->getAccessToken());

        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

        if(isset($_GET['code'])){
          $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
          $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
          header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }

        if(!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Conectar</a>";
        } 

        if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){
            print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>Salir</a><br>";
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
            $results = $service->events->listEvents('primary', array());

            if(count($results->getItems()) == 0){
              print "<h3>No hay Eventos</h3>";
            }else{
              print "<h3>Proximos Eventos</h3>";
              echo "<table border=1>";
              foreach ($results->getItems() as $event){
                echo "<tr>";
                $start = $event->start->dateTime;
                if (empty($start)){
                  $start = $event->start->date;
                }

                echo "<td>".$event->getSummary()."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$start."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

              }
                echo "<table>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
<p>Hace algo</p>
```

**EDITADO**

De esta manera, haciendo una función en el controlador (en LARAVEL), se pueden agendar eventos en calendario, necesitamos la id del calendario, esto lo podemos obtener en calendar, en ajustes del calendario donde queramos agendar. También necesitamos entrar a google console y autorizar la API de google calendar.

*Código controlador*

```
public function agendarIncidencias(Request $request){
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');


    //configurar variable de entorno / set enviroment variable
    $salida = putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/calendar-253219-f88334ba3a99.json');


    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']);

    // ID calendario
    $id_calendar = 'daviserraalonso@gmail.com';//
    

    $fechaInicio = new DateTime($request["fechaInicio"]);
    $fechaFin = new DateTime($request["fechaFin"]);

    $horaInicio = $fechaInicio->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);
    $horaFin = $fechaFin->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);

    try{
        
        //instanciamos el servicio
         $calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
     
        //crear evento
        $event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
        $event->setSummary($request["incidencia"]);
        $event->setDescription($request["detalles"]);

        //fecha inicio
        $inicio = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $inicio->setDateTime($horaInicio);
        $event->setStart($inicio);

        //fecha fin
        $fin = new \Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
        $fin->setDateTime($horaFin);
        $event->setEnd($fin);

      
        $createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert($id_calendar, $event);
        $idEvento = $createdEvent->getId();
        $linkEvento = $createdEvent->gethtmlLink();

    }catch(Google_Service_Exception $gs){
     
      $errores = json_decode($gs->getMessage());
      $errores = $errores->error->message;

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $errores = "Error aqui: ".$e->getMessage();
      
    }
}
```

**VISTA**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap pt-5">
    <div class="row">
       @include('layouts.sidebar')
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 ml-2">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="formularioCalendario">
            <label>Incidencia</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="incidencia" id="asuntoIncidencia" placeholder="Introduzca la incidencia"> 
            </div>
            <label>Detalles</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="detalles" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
            <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="fechaInicio" id="fechaInicio"> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fecha Fin</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="fechaFin" id="fechaFin"> 

                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="agendar">Crear</button>
            <div class="alert alert-success pt-3" role="alert" id="agendado"></div>
        </form><!-- FIN FORM -->
    </div>
    <!-- IFRAME PARA MOSTRAR EL CALENDARIO -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed? 
   src=daviserraalonso%40gmail.com&ctz=Europe%2FMadrid"frameborder="0" 
     scrolling="no" id="calendarioGoogle"></iframe>
    </div>
</div><!-- FIN CONTENEDOR FLEX -->
</div><!-- FIN CONTAINER -->
@endsection
```